# Error with gganimate for a polygon sf object

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, gganimate

Given
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mbbn14nnirgxsa/v.rda?dl=0

I do:

```
load("v.rda")
v$state <- 1:nrow(v)
p <- ggplot(data=v) +
  geom_sf() +
  transition_states(state)
animate(plot = p, renderer = gifski_renderer())
```

but get:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "id", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 4837 rows, data has 4786
```

Similar code works with sf point objects, so I am very confused.

Comment: Please use `dput` to share data, instead of linking to external sources.

Answer (score 0):

One of the polygons within the sf object must have a wrong geometry, the code works fine with a subset